# How to parse and retrieve PubNub message object

Tags: android, pubnub

I am building a PubNub Android app.
In this app I am receiving a message but I do not know how to access it.
For example, how do I access the text message?

This is the response:

```
hello_world {"text":"this is a sample message"}
```

**Update**

```
private void notifyUser(Object message) {

        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();

        try {

            final String obj = (String) message;

            msg.obj = obj;

            handler.sendMessage(msg);

            Log.i("Received msg : ", obj.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Updated with more code. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to access? And where? 
From you code I see that you have an incoming param message in your notifyUser() method. Is that a message you want to read? Or is it an instance of Message class?

Answer (score 0):

Does this tutorial help you? http://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/android/tutorial/data-push.html#_step_3_receive_messages

In your case, message.txt should contain "this is a sample message".

geremy